# Using Spyder (Python 3.6)... trying to use 2 format specifiers for one integer

Tags: python

I am trying to use two format specifiers for one integer, but I do not know the proper syntax. I would like to format a large number to use commas, as well as round to two decimal places.

```
print('Total = ${0:,}{0:.2f}'.format(total)) 
#prints total once with commas, then prints total again with two decimal places but no commas.
```

What is the proper way to write the print command so total is printed once with both commas and two decimal places?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mike. can you add an example with a number in input and the expected output? I don't get exactly what you want. Please add it to the question itself.

Comment: To format multiple times, you have to pass everything separated by commas on `format` call. I.E.: `print('{} and {}'.format(1, 2))`

Comment: @RodolfoDonãHosp no you don't, you can just explicitly use `0` twice in the format specifiers, as the OP has done. In fact, the OPs code *works*

Comment: Sorry, i meant if you want to use multiple values for format, the same value you can indeed use it as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain formatters like this:

```
total = 5555559.5

print('Total = ${0:,.2f}'.format(total))
```

output:

```
Total = $5,555,559.50
```